# Why is this not a regular language

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, automata

So I recently had a problem where I had to create a regular language. After consulting my professor on my solution he told me it was close to correct but to check my definition of a regular language. I am somewhat lost on why my solution is not regular?

[image: solution]

From my understanding it meets the requirements of being a right regular language since there is only one non-terminal on the right side of the expression and the non-terminal is the rightmost symbol on the right side of the expression. Are pipe symbols not allowed?

Comment: Your professor is right.  Did you check your definition of a [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar)?  What *is* the definition?  What did you do to check that your grammar meets the criteria?  Are you familiar with the notion of a right-regular grammar?  Do you know what are the conditions for a grammar to qualify as right-regular?  Please edit your question to show your work.  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own (including following up on the tip you got from your professor) before asking here, and to show what you've tried.

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format your maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivation $T_1 \to U_1$ is not right-regular.  It does not fall into the three allowed categories of rules.  See Wikipedia on [right-regular grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar#Strictly_regular_grammars).  If you have a non-terminal on the right-hand side, it needs to be preceded by a terminal.

Comment: thank you! I knew I must have been overlooking something simple. I could replace it with T1 -> aT1 | bT1 | b correct?

Comment: If the task was to give a grammar for a regular language, this grammar clearly produces a regular language as it is. If the task was to give a right-linear grammar defined without $A \to B$ being allowed as transitions, then it is not a right-regular grammar. However, we could without problem allow transitions of that form in right-regular grammars, the proof of equivalence with $\epsilon$-NFAs would work just the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment:

I still can't get why it is not right regular. As @D.W. mentioned that

> If you have a non-terminal on the right-hand side, it needs to be
>   preceded by a terminal.

But the same [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar#Strictly_regular_grammars) had another example suggesting that is not the case

A somewhat longer but more explicit right regular grammar G for the same regular expression is given by N = {S, A, B, C}, Σ = {a, b, c}, where P consists of the following rules:

```
S → A
A → aA
```

> A → B

```
B → bC
C → ε
C → cC
```

…where each uppercase letter corresponds to phrases starting at the next position in the regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, well, the example in Wikipedia is wrong.  Wikipedia has errors; this is not the only error in Wikipedia.  So it goes.  (This example grammar does qualify as what Wikipedia calls an "extended right regular grammar", and it can be transformed into a grammar that is right regular.  Also, just for added confusion points, some authors define "right regular grammar" differently, in a way that matches extended right regular grammar.)